# recreate an array where name matches with the substring and channeltype is equal to Ota

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
public data = [
        {
            'name': 'Item 1', 'channelType': 'ota'
        },
        {
            'name': 'Item 2', 'channelType': 'ota'
        },
        {
            'name': 'Item 3', 'channelType': 'ota'
        },
        {
            'name': 'Item 4', 'channelType': 'ota'
        },
        {
            'name': 'Item 5', 'channelType': 'direct'
        },
        {
            'name': 'Item 6', 'channelType': 'direct'
        },
        {
            'name': 'Item 7', 'channelType': 'direct'
        },
]
```

I would like to use filter or reduce or may be both to return all arrays where name contains a substring and channel type = ota

Let me write clearly what i want to do,

I have one text input and two check box . It all
condition 1: All the input will work together to filter the data.
condition 1: It will check if the input is a substring of name. 
condition 2: It will check if the checkbox is of channel type ota, if it is ota, it will list all the ota channel type
condition 3: It will check if the checkbox is of channel type direct, if it is direct, It will list all direct channel type
condition 4: If both of the checkbox is selected then all the data is returned and also checks for the input name for substring

Comment: are you sure, that is javascript?

Comment: Since you know about these methods, have you tried any of them?

Comment: no i havnt tried.

Comment: Simply `obj.filter((s)=> s.name.indexOf("2") != -1 && s.channelType == "ota" )`  assuming `2` is the substring you want to check.

Comment: if the user doesnt specify the string, it should fetch the type ota

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and supply the predicate that you wish to filter on.

```
const filtered = data.filter(d => d.name.includes('substring') && d.channelType === 'ota');
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you using babel to transpile your ES6 code?

Comment: Can you update your post with your latest code? Are you ensuring that you assign the return value of `filter()` to the variable you're interested in?

Comment: So `console.log(filtered)` should show the filtered?

Comment: What is the value of `filterData.lookupSource`?

Comment: Have you got the case of 'ota' correct? It's not 'Ota'?

Comment: A last question before accepting your answer. 
your code : d => d.name.includes('substring') && d.channelType === 'ota'

The above code says that name should include a substring and channel type should be ota but it returns all data of ota when channelType is only ota. shouldnt it check that the both condition to be true?

Comment: This worked like or . when i dint write anything on the search box , it pulled out all the data of type ota

Comment: Your filter string is the empty string and all strings include the empty string. e.g. 'xyz'.includes('') will be true for everything

Comment: Only apply the filter if `searchText.length > 0`

Comment: Ok thanks for your info. Please update this in the answer.

Comment: You will need to change your question then since the code does filter all objects "where name contains a substring and channel type = ota "

Comment: I want it to check if the ota is checked irrespective of the search string and also return the results if both search string and ota is specified